# Solve error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level without convert application in web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, virtual-directory

Hi when a moved my project on line i obtain this error

```
Line 19:       </assemblies>
Line 20:     </compilation>
Line 21:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 22:       <forms loginUrl="~/user_login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTHRECSHIELD" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
Line 23:     </authentication>
```

Source File: d:\www\MW_qXnIPRqPq\shieldtrust.it\shield_trust\web.config    Line: 21

**Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

To fix this error I want to talk to my provider and configure the directory into a an application or is there another way?

Comment: Please make sure  that ASPNET account has the permission to access web.config

Comment: The account has te permission. My provider configured the directory into an application and now I can see my pages

Comment: This error mainly occurs when you open a new website of your project,If a folder is added to website then there will be two webconfig. For ex: let us assume you have a folder `Project` placed inside a folder `Project1` Then if you open `Project1` website then mainly this orrur occurs.Just close the application and then open `Project`.your error will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

For me, in the IIS, I had not converted the correct folder to Application. So while browsing, I was getting this error.
Once I converted the proper folder to application and hit browse, it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

There can be one of many possible reasons for this

1. You may have added a backup folder inside the main folder. If yes, Remove it.
2. Make sure that you have opened the correct root folder, in case you are running the project with Visual Studio
3. Make sure that you don't have any copy of web.config files kept in the project.

Hopefully it helps.
In case you are still experiencing the same problem, let me know :)